# can an (IBAction) method be sent a message?

Tags: objective-c, ibaction

I want to delay between each output result for say, 1 second. The very last line of the following code is throwing an error "Use of undeclared identifier 'dealCard'", but I have declared it in the header file as shown below.

```
- (IBAction)startPause:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.deal length]>cardNum) {
        timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(dealCard) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        card.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",cardNum];
        [timer fire];
    }
}


- (void) dealCard{
    NSLog(@"dealCard: %d: ", cardNum+self.randCut);
    cardNum=cardNum + 1;
    [self startPause:(id)dealCard];
}
```

header file is next.

```
- (IBAction) startPause:(id)sender ;
- (void) dealCard;
```

Comment: This code makes no sense. You have one method that calls another, which then sets up a timer to call the first method again, and _immediately fires_ that timer, which hasn't been scheduled anyways. You need to rethink whatever it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a compilation error because `dealCard` is not a variable in the `dealCard` method.  You *can* pass a selector as an argument.  That would be done like:

```
[self startPause:@selector(dealCard)];
```

or even

```
[self startPause:_cmd];
```

since `_cmd` gives you the current selector and you happen to be in `dealCard`.  Note however that *usually* the "sender" parameter is not used for passing a selector, but an object.  For example an instance of `UIButton` sending a message like:

```
- (IBAction)myButtonResponse:(id)sender;
```

would pass `self` for the sender parameter.

Comment: I am not trying to use  ": (id) sender". So, if I omit the that, do I still use @selector(dealCard) somehow?

Comment: If you're not going to use the `sender` parameter in `startPause:` you can just pass `nil` when you call `startPause:`, like `[self startPause:nil];`

Comment: Nevermind. I think I had a mixture of method declarations and calls, some with ": (id)sender" and some without. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can call your `IBAction` method with

```
[self startPause:nil];
```

since the `sender` parameter is never used. Remember that `dealCard` is a method, which has a selector associated. It's not a property (not even an object), so you can't pass it as an argument using only its name.

You have a recursive problem, too. `dealCard` calls `startPause:`, and `startPause:` calls `dealCard` again. You should have a stop condition in `dealCard` to end the "two level" recursive calls.

Comment: Thanks for your edit @JoshCaswell! i'm just starting to write in english so i'll have a lot of errors.

Comment: You're welcome. It was a very good foundation; only a little English editing was necessary.