# no delay achieved with NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I want to delay between each output result for say, 1 second. The code below is not delaying but is processing correctly. Why is it not delaying between each `dealCard`?

```
- (IBAction)startPause
{
    if ([self.deal length]>cardNum) {
        timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(dealCard) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        [timer fire];
    }
}


- (void) dealCard{
    card.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",cardNum+1];
    cardTo.text = [self.deal substringWithRange:(NSRange){(cardNum+self.randCut)%[self.cardList count],1}];
    cardNum=cardNum + 1;
    [self startPause];
}
```

Comment: Because, [as I commented on your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034993/can-an-ibaction-method-be-sent-a-message#comment24624911_17034993), you're immediately firing the timer (which isn't scheduled anyways). What did you think `[timer fire];` would do?

Comment: you need to read docs about `NSTimer` first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) `fire` "Causes the receiver’s message to be sent to its target." Which is why it's firing instantly.

Your timer is also not scheduled, so it would never fire on it's own.

Create your timer like this instead, which creates a timer, and schedules it in a single statement.

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(dealCard)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:NO];
```

And remove the `[timer fire]` line completely, as it will fire itself after it's time interval is up.

Comment: That is the answer. I tried to edit the answer to capitalize the C in `dealCard` but was unsuccessful. I thought `fire` started the timer, for those who asked. Now I need to put a blank output between each one, or animate each one. Is there an easy way to do that?