# identify a storyboard uibutton for editting in code

Tags: ios, button, storyboard

**update 1**

I fixed the problem of the loop not stopping by putting the condition in `dealCard` instead of in `startPause`.

**update 1**

**update 0**

```
- (IBAction)startPause: (UIButton *)sender{
    NSString *buttonTitle = sender.currentTitle;
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString: @"Pause"]) {

        [self.myButton setTitle:@"Resume" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [timer invalidate];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.myButton setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        if ([self.deal length]>cardNum) {
            timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(dealCard)
                                                   userInfo:nil
                                                    repeats:YES];
        }
        else
            [timer invalidate];

    }
}
```

In addition to the revised code above, I added a `IBOutlet` property for `myButton` as suggested by multiple folks, and changed the `NSTimer` to `repeats:YES` from `repeats:NO`, and I removed the call `[self startPause]` from `dealCard`. Now the system seems to work except that the failure of the "while" condition `self.deal length]>cardNum` does not properly invalidate  the `NSTimer` in the `else` clause.

I could use some feedback about why that invalidate is not getting fired.

**update 0**

[Continuing this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055297/no-delay-achieved-with-nstimer/17055382#17055382), I am trying to add the "Pause" part of a "startPause" UIButton. After the button is tapped, I want its title and action to be "Pause", and I want its title to toggle then between "Resume" and "Pause".

The button is created in Storyboard and I cannot think of how to create an identifier for the button so I can alter it programatically. I suspect I need to enhance the button's `IBAction` method to include "sender" now, but I may be way off.

Currently I have the following unfinished code.

```
- (IBAction)startPause: (UIButton *)sender{
    NSString *buttonTitle = sender.currentTitle;
    if ([buttonTitle isEqual: @"Pause"]) {
    [myButton setTitle:@"Resume" forState:UIControlStateNormal];   //**** myButton is what?     

    if ([self.deal length]>cardNum) {
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(dealCard)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:NO];
    }
    }
}
```

(I know I have not started the "else" part of the code.)

How do I hook up `myButton` above with my `startPause` button in the Storyboard?

Comment: Did you link the `touch up inside` event to your IBAction from storyboard ?

Comment: are you trying to alter the button's action programmatically? Do you have it wired up at all that the above code is fired upon pressing the button?

Comment: Sorry I did not see these comments before. Yes, I do have `touch up inside` linked up in the Storyboard. And yes I am trying to alter the button's title programmatically and the above code is fired when the button is tapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a few things wired up wrong in Storyboard. For your UIButton (myButton) you should have two hooks into your .h file

```
(1) @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
(2) - (IBAction)startPause:(id)sender;
```

(1) will allow you to set your button title anywhere within your .m file, specifically in your myButtonAction event.
(2) when you wired the button to your .h file you should have chosen touchUpInside, that way when the button is tapped the event myButtonAction will fire.

EDIT2 (to address NSTimer)

```
- (IBAction)startPause: (UIButton *)sender{
NSString *buttonTitle = sender.currentTitle;
if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString: @"Pause"]) {

    [self.myButton setTitle:@"Resume" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [timer invalidate];
}
else
{
    [self.myButton setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if ([self.deal length]>cardNum) 
    {
      if (!myTimer.isValid)
       {
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(dealCard)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:YES];
       }
       else
       {
         //do nothing - timer has been created already
       }
    }
    else 
    {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
}
```

[This doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003747) may also help.

Comment: Are you saying that I need to do the second recommendation that Aaron made in his answer and add an `IBOutlet` as well as the `IBAction` I already have? And I also need the `sender` in the `IBAction`? Thanks.

Comment: The IBAction handles just that... the action of being pressed (in your case). The IBOutlet allows you to manipulate the object in the view.

If you only wire up the IBAction you can only respond to the button being touched. Likewise if you only wire up the IBOutlet you have a programmatically editable button that doesn't respond to being touched.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the IBAction handles the press of the button, and the IBOutlet will enable me to return from the `dealCard` method. Do I need the `sender`, also, to access the button's title? I am pretty sure the answer is yes. So, at the end of `dealCard` what is my command? Is it, `[self startPause: @"myButton"]`, or what?

Comment: I guess I'm missing why you're trying to manually call startPause... it's called every time you touch the button. To change the title of the button you have the correct code above via [myButton setTitle:@"New Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal]. I'll update my answer to see if I can get to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am manually calling `startPause` to create a sort of continuous or repeating "while" loop, where the `startPause` method contains the condition for the loop to continue.

Comment: I think there is a small problem with your .h code; shouldn't the method there `myButtonAction` really be `startPause:`? But I think the bigger issue is my question about `dealCard` calling `startPause:` because `dealCard` is NOT a UIButton, so how can it supply a `sender`?

Comment: I think I have the beginning of a solution. Instead of `repeats:NO` use `repeats:YES` and omit the call of `startPause` in `dealCard`. Now I am trying to find/remember how to disable/kill the `NSTimer` when the while condition ends.

Comment: Please see my **update** in the original question. And thanks.

Comment: No problem. Thx for the copy/paste callout on the .h code. Regarding killing a timer use [myTimer invalidate]. Good luck!

Comment: @zerowords: I updated the above example earlier today... see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `sender` parameter of your `startPause` method should be the `UIButton` you want, so you can probably get away with modifying `sender` directly.  That is, replace `myButton` with `sender` in your code snippet.

Another way to go, which has the advantage that if you pause/resume from anywhere else you can still get at the button and update its title, is to make an `IBOutlet` for the button.  In your class `@interface` section you'll have something like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *pauseResumeButton;
```

and then when you want to reference the button you can use either `self.pauseResumeButton` or `_pauseResumeButton`.

Comment: Thanks. Believe it or not, I had just tried changing `myButton` to `sender`, but then I was up against the next problem (that follows). The `dealCard` method used to have the last line `[self startPause]`. Does that last instruction now need to be something like `[self startPause: sender]`? and what is `sender`? Or what?

Comment: No, the `startPause:` method is called when you touch the button. You don't have to call it in your code. The `sender` is a pointer to the object which invoked the method call, so in this case the `UIButton` that you touched.

Comment: But, I want continuous returns to `startPause:...` until the returns are paused, so I need that last line, but I don't know how to change it.