# Is it possible for a uibutton to set the title of another uibutton seeing that both were created in the storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

I have just started coding not too long ago, so apologies in advance for any glaringly obvious mistakes.

I have created both buttons using the storyboard. I understand that you can change the sender button's title like how [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074176/identify-a-storyboard-uibutton-for-editting-in-code) stated it, but I was still not sure how to change the other button title when the first one is clicked. I have tried referencing tags, but nothing happened when I clicked the first button. Is it possible to do this? Please give an example if it is.

**Goal:** Change the title of one button by clicking another button, both created with Storyboard.

Comment: Just create your uibutton outlet from storybaord for both buttons and actions to so in first button action just settitle of second button like this ` button.setTitle(“buttontitle”,for:.normal)`

Comment: You are on the right way. Are you sure you used the right method (*setTitle:forState:*) instead of just setTitle:?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'll answer to this question even if there already are correct answers because they both are showing swift solutions even if the question is expicitly about Objective C)

The simplest way, as stated in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51834300/2661320), is to assign outlets to the buttons. Ctrl-drag from the button in Interface Builder to the @interface of your ViewController and give the button an outlet name:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
@end
```

Then, in the first button's IBAction, call the setTitle:forControlState: method of the second button outlet

```
- (IBAction)button1Tapped:(id)sender {
    [self.button2 setTitle:@"new title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

As an alternative, you can also use storyboard tags (the fact that i used a UIView and then checked *if isKindOfClass* is to avoid crashes in case you mistakenly assign the same tag to some non-UIButton object):

```
- (IBAction)button1Tapped:(id)sender {
    UIView *buttonView = [self.view viewWithTag:1002];
    if ([buttonView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class] ]) {
        [(UIButton *)buttonView setTitle:@"new title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two solution to achieve this:

1. By using **IBOutlets**
2. By using **Storyboard tags**

> Using IBOutlets, you can create an outlet of second button e.g. 
>   `@IBOutlet weak var btnSecond: UIButton!`
>   Now change the title of this button in action of first button like this:

```
@IBAction clickFirstBtn(sender: UIButton){
  btnSecond.set("New Title", for: .normal)
}
```

> Using storyboard tags, you can give any tag to second button except 0. For example let the tag of second button = 10.
>   Now you change the title like this:

```
@IBAction clickFirstBtn(sender: UIButton){
     if let btnSecond = view.viewWithTag(10) as? UIButton{
       btnSecond.set("New Title", for: .normal)
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have `Button1` and `Button2` and you want to set the title of `Button2` onclick of `Button1`.
You can do it by creating an action on the click of `Button1` and setting the title of `Button2` on this action..

**Swift 3**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   Button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setTitle), for: .touchUpInside)
 }

 @objc func setTitle()
 {
     Button2.setTitle("Button Title",for: UIControlState.Normal)
 }
```